# pandas if column is true, perform percent change on that row

Tags: python, boolean

I have a df with an additional column of boolean values based off a conditional statement.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3,2.5,5,2]})
df['bool'] =  df['col1'] >= 3
```

The df looks like...

```
    col bool
0   1.0 False
1   2.0 False
2   3.0 True
3   2.5 False
4   5.0 True
5   2.0 False
```

I would like to get `pct_change()` of "col1" if "bool" is true and if false return NaN. The output should look something like...

```
    col pct_change
0   1.0 NaN
1   2.0 NaN
2   3.0 -0.169
3   2.5 NaN
4   5.0 -0.400
5   2.0 NaN
```

What would be the best way of going about this?

Comment: How did you calculate your sample `pct_change`?

Comment: @Chris, sorry took an average by accedent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `numpy.where` to use `df["bool"]` as a boolean mask:

```
df["pct_change"] = np.where(df["bool"], df["col"].pct_change().shift(-1), np.nan)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   col   bool  pct_change
0  1.0  False         NaN
1  2.0  False         NaN
2  3.0   True   -0.166667
3  2.5  False         NaN
4  5.0   True   -0.400000
5  3.0  False         NaN
```